# Kinetic mathematical model of glycolysis?

Tags: metabolism, theoretical-biology, literature

I am looking for papers containing kinetic mathematical models of glycolysis, hopefully in mammalian cells (or as close as possible, say yeast). The papers I have found do qualitative analysis (bifurcations, stability analysis, etc.), but do not actually fit the model to data, so you cannot be sure of the accuracy of the kinetic constants involved. The work I need to do depends critically on having reasonably accurate estimates of those kinetic constants.